# Ensuring a %SYS class can reference a class from another namespace

Tags: intersystems-ensemble

The DeepSee.UserPortal.Workflow.zen in %SYS controls the workflow user portal. However, when a user enters something in the box marked with "GO", a "CLASS DOES NOT EXIST" error results. The class that is not being found exits and is compiled in a different namespace. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create %ALL namespace and [map package](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSA_config#GSA_config_namespace_addmap_all) with your class into it. It would be visible everywhere. Or you can just [map package](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSA_config#GSA_config_namespace_addmap_pkg) into your %SYS namespace.